# immutable.js Map not persisting data

Tags: javascript, redux, immutable.js

Using an immutable Map in a redux application

Have the following in my reducer code:

```
    const IWT = new Map();
    for (const item of action.IWT) {
        let current = IWT[item.index];
        if (current) {
            current
                .get('services')
                .push(item.SID);
        } else {
            current = new IWTObject({
                index: item.ID,
                stage: item.stage,
                name: item.name,
                ranking: item.rank,
                services: new List([item.SID]),
            });

            console.log(current, item.ID, IWT);
            IWT.set(item.ID, current);
            console.log(IWT);
        }
    }
```

For some reason, I'm getting output for `current`, `item.ID` and `IWT` in the first `console.log()` output, but I'm still getting a blank Immutable `Map` for IWT in the second output.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Due to immutability :) `set` creates new map because original map is IMMUTABLE :)

Comment: well, I feel silly. I guess the best thing to do is to build up an object iteratively and then set the map to that.

Comment: If you have multiple mutations to do in a loop take a look at `withMutations` method https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/withMutations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `const newIWT = IWT.set(item.ID, current);` and then `console.log` that out Immutable.js is designed to not mutate and instead returns a new value.

I would also recommend using immutable methods for iteration as opposed to a for loop if you are going to be using immutable.js methods such as `map` for list or the methods `keySeq` or `valueSeq` for a Map type.